# Create a pop up from a image

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

in my website I have a share option with a facebook icon, that when clicked it open a webpage in a new page, I wanted to try to implement a pop up to open in the original page but with the same content, is it a specific type of target that needs to be called?

Here I leave a code sample:

The "_blank" in the code is the target.

```
if(strpos($atts['on'], "fb") !== false) $html .= aTag("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=".$atts['href'], getImgTagByImageName($atts['fb-icon']), "_blank", $atts['id'], $atts['class']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures])`.

Would be something like:

```
window.open('http://fb.com', 'fbShareWindow', 'height=[HEIGHT], width=[WIDTH], top=[TOP], left=[LEFT], toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
```

Try the snippet below on jsfiddle. It won't work in here, cause both SO and Fiddle blocks code containing pop ups.

```js
window.share = function() {
  window.open('http://fb.com', 'fbShareWindow', 'height=[HEIGHT], width=[WIDTH], top=[TOP], left=[LEFT], toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="share();">Share me</button>
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to create a popup.https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp
In you case inside:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!
 <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>//your image goes here
</div>
```